# Как вернуть четные элементы массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Чтобы получить: 2ой, 4ый, 6ой, и т. д.
Т.е. для этого нужно использовать нечётные индексы.

Входной: `array = [1,-1,-1,1,2,-2,-2,2]`

Требуемый результат: `array = [-1,1,-2,2]`

Моё решение:

```
arr = [1,-1,-1,1,2,-2,-2,2]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        print(arr[i], end = '')
```

Мой результат: `-11-22`

Как это в массив вывести, чтобы `[-1,1,-2,2]` получилось?

Comment: `print(arr[1::2])`

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
arr = [1,-1,-1,1,2,-2,-2,2]
print('array = ', end='')
print([arr[i] for i in range(1, len(arr), 2)], sep=',')
```

`array = [-1, 1, -2, 2]`

Отличный вариант из комментария от @andreymal:

```
arr = [1,-1,-1,1,2,-2,-2,2]
print('array = ', end='')
print(arr[1::2])
```

Answer (score -2):

добавляете числа в строку через пробел а потом делаете arr = arr.split(' ').

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, небольшой пример кода. Очень интересно посмотреть на реализацию.